# PyDev plugin not working with Eclipse IDE 2020-03

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have followed the below steps for installing the PyDev plugin -

1. Used this to install from Eclipse marketplace - https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse
2. Updated my eclipse.ini with **-vm** argument pointing to the java 8 jdk as below :

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\javaw.exe

Yet, after installation PyDev options don't show up under **Windows > Preferences**.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This solved now, I had to run the eclipse in administrator mode and then perform the installation.

Comment: if not have admin access?